# Is it bad to save data as ActionController::Parameters in a postgres DB with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, postgresql

Here is the situation. I use facebook login and want to save the array of friends into my rails server with a postgres database.

The params coming in for the fb_friends are:

```
"fb_friends"=>[{"id"=>"1381984758791468", "name"=>"ios ipod"}]
```

Api controller strong parameters:
`user_params` has `fb_friends: [:id, :name]`

In the User model, I serialize fb_friends.

```
serialize :fb_friends
```

All this work but I notice that the class type for my fb_friend is `ActionController::Parameters` and it behaves like a Hash. Is this a bad thing?

In Rails console,

```
u.fb_friends.first.class
 => ActionController::Parameters

u.fb_friends.first[:id]
 => "1381984758791468"

u.fb_friends.first[:name]
 => "ios ipod"
```

EDIT:

Forgot to add my schema/migration

Migraton:

```
change_column :users, :fb_friends, :text
```

Schema for users table:

```
t.text     "fb_friends",      default: "{}"
```

Comment: Why would someone vote to close this? :(

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it works for you, but a better practice would to create a model called `FacebookFriend` so that each of your models / database tables have only one purpose.

```
FacebookFriend(id, user_id, facebook_friend_id, name, created_at, updated_at)

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :facebook_friends
end

class FacebookFriend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You could also do a "has many through" relationship if you think that your users will often have common FacebookFriends.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are going to deserialize it and use it as an ActionController::Parameters instance you should probably convert it to a standard hash. For extra points use hstore in postgres and you can still search etc..

Comment: How would I do that in code? In the User.rb model class? In the controller?

Comment: perhaps just serialize :fb_friends.to_json or something similar.. don't have time to test right now. either way one of to_a, to_h, to_json should change it into a more vanilla data type.